# Express - Do not render POST response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js, express

I have a basic Express API:

```
app.get('/example', function(req, res) {
  if (req.body.messageid == 1) {
    res.send({message: "Message"});
  }
}
```

All it does is returning a message that should then be displayed on a HTML page.

In order to display the message, I implemented this ajax call with jquery:

```
$('#view-message').on('click', function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/example",
    data: { messageid: 1},
    contentType: "text/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "text",
    success: function (msg) {
      $('#content').text(msg);
    },
    error: function (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  });
});
```

Instead of displaying the message, it just renders a new page with the content `{message: "Message"}` and not just displays the message in the existing page.

How can I make it not render the result?

Comment: you are doing a POST request, but the express route only shows a "GET" request, also if you are returning Json you should use res.json(...) instead of send()

Comment: @Davidlrnt is right, make those changes and it should work. Also make sure you're running the POST through body-parser (specifically it's json parser module) middleware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put `index.html` in `public`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>

    <div id="content"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>

    <script>
    $.ajax
    ({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost:8080/example",
        data: { messageid: 1},
        dataType: "json",
        cache : false,
        success: function (data) {
            $('#content').text(data.message);
        },
        error: function (err) {
          console.log(err);
        }
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

and in `index.js`

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var path = require('path');

var app = express();

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.post('/example', function(req, res) {
  if (req.body.messageid == 1) {
    res.send({message: "Message"});
  }
});

app.listen(8080);
```

**it works**

Comment: It does indeed work, thank you. Also, the cache parameter is important.

Comment: yeah, not compulsory ,but you should use it when you need fresh data.